# Android animation flickering

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using android animation to hide and revel a pop up screen. I am showing it at very bottom of screen. Here are the two animation files I am using

enter_from_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
    >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="0%p" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="100" />

</set>
```

exit_to_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false">

    <alpha
        android:duration="0"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="0"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

This is how I display or hide pop over view

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    MapSlideUpDetailsFragment fragment = MapSlideUpDetailsFragment.newInstance(tradeMen, dragView);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_bottom, R.anim.exit_to_bottom)
                            .replace(R.id.tradeDetailsMapOverlay, fragment)
                            .addToBackStack("MAP_SLIDE_UP_DETAILS")
                            .commit();
```

while one view goes down the other one pops in. But when the view is leaving i see a flickering effect.

How to avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: probably you should use setFillAfter method.

Comment: @Zach are you using some sort of `AnimationListener` for this animation?

Comment: No, I am not using animation listener. How to use that?

Comment: Like this: `myAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {` ...

Comment: I have updated my question to include more details. Can you all please look. I am not sure how to use animation listener in this case.